# QGIS Map Server: This WMS service has a layer limit of 99 per request

Tags: wms, qgis-server

I got the error message trying to establish a QGIS WMS:

> One or more layers failed to draw.
>
> QGIS Map Server: This WMS service has a layer limit of 99 per request.

I did not find anyone who already had this problem.

Comment: You have probably run into a max limit on open files for your OS. However, you have provided practically no additional information, beyond the noted error. Also, it is unclear if you mean the error is originating from a QGIS Server (providing a WMS service), or a completely different server, e.g. a WMS layer as part of your project that is being served by QGIS Server, etc.

Comment: It was a first simple test. I published a service out of one shapefile on a local machine. If I try to open this local service I get the error message.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem, you should put MAX_CACHE_LAYERS to 255 or higher in your fcgid environment.